# fprintf not printing Unicode character

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, mfc

This morning I found a very weird problem and I can't find the solution. Please help me solve this problem with the code below (using Visual Studio C++ and MFC):

```
FILE *fp = NULL;
//fp = fopen(mmFileName , "a");
//Store the module directory path
fopen_s( &fp , "TempWorking.xml" , "wb");
//char* TempChar;
CString strtempff;
strtempff = "\"&lt;article&gt;  &lt;section class=&quot;page&quot;&gt;&lt;p&gt;Writing for the clown show that is &lt;em&gt;Forbes&lt;/em&gt;, Darcy Travlos asks the &lt;a href=&quot;http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betteridge%27s_law_of_headlines&quot;&gt;Betteridgeâ€™s Law&lt;/a&gt;-challenging question â€œApple And Google: The New â€˜Oldâ€™ Reality?â€ (No link but tip oâ€™ the an";
char* TempArray;
TempArray = new char[strtempff.GetLength()];
strcpy(TempArray,strtempff.GetString());
strtempff = "";
strtempff.Empty();
fprintf(fp,(char*)TempArray);
```

I don't know why my code is not working at the `fprintf()` statement: it gives me a debug assertion. `strtempff` is collected from the net, it's just an example in the code.

Comment: It's probably weird, not weard.

Comment: Ok ok weird but its problem

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes nop its not working with TempArray[strtempff.GetLength()-1] = '\0';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your error is that you are providing a string to fprintf which is not a format string. You should do:

```
fprintf(fp,"%s",(char*)TempArray);
```

To explain, any % characters in your string will be confusing it, since those are special format characters for the printf family of functions. The other comments about insufficient buffer length are also correct and you need to fix that too.

You might also want to use `fwprintf` and wide strings, since you're trying to print an extended character set. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/fwprintf/

Comment: `TempArray` is already a `char*`, there is no need to cast it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau also true. I was simply copying his code with the minimum necessary changes.

Answer (score 1):

The [`CString::GetLength()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300471%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) function does not include the 0-terminator, so you're declaring a too small array.

For instance if the `CString` is "a", then `GetLength()` will return 1, and you will allocate a `TempArray` of 1 character, but then `strcpy()` will write 2 characters since it *will* terminate the string, causing a buffer overflow and undefined behavior.

Comment: TempArray = new char[strtempff.GetLength()+2]; is also not working??

Comment: TempArray = new char[strtempff.GetLength()+10]; also not working..